# difference between DataType and Class in python

Tags: python, class, object, types

what's the difference between DataType and Class ?? 
is a class allows to create a new datatype which we define on our own? like str, int, list ...
if not I want to know what are the built-in classes in python.
and finally, I want a simple definition of an object with some examples.

Comment: Is this homework? See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) Also welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: Are you asking about NumPy datatypes?

Answer (score 0):

A type denotes a certain interface, i.e. a set of signatures,
whereas a class tells us how an object is implemented (like a
blueprint). A class can have many types if it implements all their
interfaces, and different classes can have the same type if they share a
common interface. More specifically -

A `type` is a `class` that can be used as a template for additional classes by way of inheritance. Example-

```
class Myclass(Test):
```

A `class` is a Python data structure that can be used as a template for instances of that class by calling it. Example -

```
Myclass= Myclass().
```

You can read bit more in theory [here](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/).